# iPhone xml parsing/editing a better solution?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I use GDataXML for parsing the XML I received from my webservice, actually I only parse the part that I need and then I want to "edit" that XML and send it back to Webservice.

I checked some GDataXML examples but they were about saving XML as model objects and creating an XML from model objects again.

Because speed is important what I want is without saving or converting that xml into model objects I just want to edit/delete some nodes on it and send it back quickly as possible.

Actually I can do this by simply converting it into string and do string manipulation. But I dont think editing XML as a string is a safe way.

How can I do this better?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I tend to use a XML to NSDictionary object that I found on google which saves a lot of time parsing and configuring the XML. Try that out.